# jquery Countdown serverSync not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, countdown

I am using the jquery countdown serverSync feature as mentioned http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#serverSync, but I can't get the countdown to sync to the servertime. My code as written in the documentation:

```
$(selector).countdown({
    until: liftoffTime,
    serverSync: serverTime
});

function serverTime() {
    var time = null;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myserver.com/serverTime.php',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (text) {
            time = new Date(text);
        },
        error: function (http, message, exc) {
            time = new Date();
        }
    });
    alert("Debug server time: " + time);
    return time;
}
```

my php code in serverTime.php

```
<?php 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>
```

When I alert in the javascript the time the output is:

> Sun Jun 24 2012 12:02:23 GMT+0100 (BST)

However when I just go to http://myserver.com/serverTime.php the time is displayed in this format:

> Jun 24, 2012 12:03:35 +0100

Very different. Can anyone shed any light on why it's not syncing and could the different date formats returned be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Your `php` and `serverTime()` code works correct.

The different time format is not the issue and not the internal `Date` representation.

What values do you assign to `selector` and `liftoffTime` variables?

Here is my workling test:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ajax count down test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script> <!--maybe you shouldn't hotlink this file ;-) -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
<script>
    function serverTime() {
        var time = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'serverTime.php',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (text) {
                time = new Date(text);
            },
            error: function (http, message, exc) {
                time = new Date();
            }
        });
        return time;
    }

    $(function () {
        $("#defaultCountdown").countdown({
            until: new Date("Jun 24, 2012 16:00:00 +0000"),
            serverSync: serverTime
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions, just leave a comment.